# PHP code: echo form data to a table

Tags: php

I have this code,
it should print form data submitted into table of 2 cols and show it same page
but it doesn't  work

Any help please

NogDog

```
  <?php 
 if(isset($_POST['submit'])) 
 { 
 $bits = ''; 
 // use preg_split so I can use the NO_EMPTY modifier 
 $cells = preg_split('/=/', $bits, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY); 
 $rows = array_chunk($cells, 2); 
 } 
 ?> 
 <table>
<tr>
    <th>
        Col 1
    </th>
    <th>
        Col 2
    </th>
</tr>
<form method="post" action="
<?php 
foreach($rows as $row) { 
echo "<tr>"; 
foreach($row as $cell) { 
    echo "<td>".htmlspecialchars($cell)."</td>"; 
}  
 } 
?>">
    <input type="text" name="poet">
    <br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Form">
        <br>
        </form>
 </table>
```

Comment: you need to improve your `form`.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! You say "it doesn't work", but you need to explain exactly what you expect it to do, and what it does instead.

Comment: @WillSheppard Thank you very much. I expect : 1- input data (sentence) to text-area 2- split it to two parts 3- display data inputted to table every part in different columns   4-also every line has a row , every row with 2 cols .. Sorry if my English is weak I hope you understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code. It's working as you said. First I thought it was a dump question but it works!!!

```
  <?php 
  if(isset($_POST['submit'])) 
  { 
      $bits = $_POST['poet']; 
     // use preg_split so I can use the NO_EMPTY modifier 
      $cells = preg_split('/ /', $bits, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY); 
      $rows = array_chunk($cells, 2); 
   } 
  ?> 
  <table>
  <tr>
     <th>
       Col 1
     </th>
     <th>
       Col 2
     </th>
  </tr>
 <?php 
 foreach($rows as $row) { 
 echo "<tr>"; 
    foreach($row as $cell) { 
      echo "<td>".htmlspecialchars($cell)."</td>"; 
    }  
 }
 ?>
 <form method="post" action="">
 <input type="text" name="poet">
 <br>
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Form">
  <br>
  </form>
 </table>
```

Comment: Nice but it splits characters not words!!

Comment: Sorry I forget. to edit, but it works as I request. Thank you very much!!

Comment: To split words you just need to put a space between those two '/'s. `'/ /'`. I modified the answer code above.

Comment: do you have odesk account send it please if you able to develop this code with more functions

Comment: I don't have an odesk account.. Do you want me to create one ?

Comment: skype please to contact you

Comment: myskype ID w8.u@hotmail.com

Answer (score 0):

You have not close tr tag within foreach loop

```
 <table>
 <tr>
<th>
    Col 1
</th>
<th>
    Col 2
</th>
</tr>
<form method="post" action="
 <?php 
 foreach($rows as $row) { 
 echo "<tr>"; 
 foreach($row as $cell) { 
echo "<td>".htmlspecialchars($cell)."</td>"; 
}  
 } 
?>">
```

Comment: Thank you, when I put it as you wrote it did not work.

Comment: you want to display data when you submit form